# show today's date in placeholder of a text box

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to show current date in a text box place holder using jquery in which I am using date-picker before clicking the text box

Comment: you should share what you have tried so far.

Comment: show some relevant code. Create a fiddle if possible.

Comment: how about `new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)`

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1):

Separated

```
<input id="day" name="day" type="number" placeholder="<?=Date('j')?>" />
<input id="month" name="month" type="number" placeholder="<?=Date('n')?>" />
<input id="year" name="year" type="number" placeholder="<?=Date('Y')?>" />
```

Combined (Format: Day-Month-Year)

```
<input id="date" name="date" type="number" placeholder="<?=Date('j-n-Y')?>" />
```

Customize your format by viewing the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: thanks dude.It works but I need the date format like this 11-Dec-14

Comment: Use <?=Date('j-M-y')?> instead, M = Month in three letters, y = Year in 2 digits.

Comment: can you please make it in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Since you require the placeholder you could set the attribute of the text box using jquery `.attr()`. Try something like this:

`$('#fieldID').attr('placeholder', new Date());`
You will get the date and you can format it as required.

Comment: it is not working bro

Answer (score 0):

You can read HTML and Jquery tutorial. that will help to understand concepts in more details.

```
var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
    ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
    ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;


$('#date').val(output);
```

try it here : http://jsfiddle.net/nCE9u/